# How we use 's' or 'es'

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement

I have a question can someone explain me why in this sentence

> The fact I haven't been in school for more than a month amazes me

why in the word 'amaze' we add 's' is it because more than is plurality so we can add 's' to adjective word?

Can adjective be plural?

Thank you for answer my question, fyi I'm not an English native speaker.

Answer (score 4):

The word *amazes* in that sentence is a verb. The adjective would be *amazing*.

It gets an 's' because it's being conjugated with "fact":

> That fact amazes me.
>   Those two facts amaze me, also.
>   Three other facts amazed me yesterday.
>   Maybe some other face will amaze me tomorrow.

As an adjective:

> I heard an amazing fact yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the sentence is

> The fact I haven't been in school for more than a month

This is  third person singular. This includes *the fact* and the reduced relative clause *(that) I haven't been in school for more than a month*.

The verb is *[amazes](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/amaze_1)*, whose form is also for third person singular. (Note that we find the *-s* ending only on third person singular verbs.)

*To amaze* usually requires a direct object  and here it is *me*.

As to the question regarding adjectives, in English adjectives do not have singular or plural forms.